# Trabajar matrices 2D python

Tags: python

Trabajar listas de 2d (creo que se conoce cómo matrices).

¿Cómo se hace para ir rellenandolas? Se que es básico pero no lo entiendo.

Yo se que si tengo

```
lista1 = []
for x in xrange (0,5):
    lista1.append(x)
print lista1
```

Relleno mi lista de manera que queda cómo: [0,1,2,4]

Pero en mi caso yo querría hacer "dos columnas" (realmente en una quiero poner letras y en otra números) ¿Cómo hago para asignar el valor que yo quiera a la primera columna y el valor que yo quiera a la segunda columna? Empleo `.append()` y me da error y si lo asigno con un signo igual también.

```
lista2 = [[],[]]

lista2[[0][0]].append('a')
lista2[[0][1]].append(1)
print lista2
```

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Ahora mismo te respondo, deja formular bien la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para crear una matriz lo que se hace es una lista de listas por ejemplo:

```
matriz = [
    [" ", 1, 2, 3, 4], # Fila 0
    ["A", 1, 2, 3, 4], # Fila 1
    ["B", 1, 2, 3, 4], # Fila 2
    ["C", 1, 2, 3, 4], # Fila 3
    ["D", 1, 2, 3, 4]  # fila 4
    # Columnas
]
```

**Para acceder a la fila 1 y columna 3**

```
fila = 1
columna = 3
print(matriz[fila][columna]
```

**Para asignar un nuevo valor a una fila y columna**

```
matriz[fila][columna] = "N"
# Para una mejor visualización usa pretty print
from pprint import pprint
pprint(matriz)
```

**Agregar un nuevo elemento a la fila 2**

```
fila = 2
matriz[fila].append("NuevoElemento")
from pprint import pprint
pprint(matriz)
```

Answer (score 1):

En python una matriz se puede representar como una lista de lista, por ejemplo, tenemos la  `matriz = [[],[],[]]` la misma contiene tres listas, estas listas indicarion las filas en la matriz, y los valores contenidos dentro de cada una de estas listas indicaria una columna en la matriz, para esta lista de listas,  `matriz = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],[5,6,7]]`la matriz quedaria asi: 
`1 2 3
a b c
5 6 7`
 
la primera fila seria la primera lista, la segunda fila seria la segunda lista y asi sucesivamente, para las columnas lo mismo, la primera columna seria todos los elementoen la primera posiscion de todas las listas, la segunda columna todos los elemntos de la segunda posicion en todas las listas y asi sucesivamentem, para crear una matriz cuadrada, la cantidad de elemntos en las listas debe ser igual, y por ende igual al tamaño de la lista contenedora, en este caso `matriz` un ejemplo mas practico:

`matriz = []
for fila in range(4):
    fila_nueva=[]
    for columna in range(4):
        fila_nueva.append(str("celda"+str(fila+1,columna+1))))
    matriz.append(fila_nueva)`

con esto deberia quedar algo asi

`celda 1,1 celda 1,2 celda 1,3 celda 1,4
celda 2,1 celda 2,2 celda 2,3 celda 2,4
celda 3,1 celda 3,2 celda 3,3 celda 3,4
celda 4,4 celda 4,2 celda 4,3 celda 4,4`

por lo que para acceder a un elemento debes de llamar primero en que fila buscar y luego en que posisicon de esa lista, por ejemplo para sacar el elemento que esta en la celda 3, 3, seria  `elemento = matriz[2][2]`